# Parsing strings with numbers and SI prefixes in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have this dataframe:

```
>>> import polars
>>> df = polars.DataFrame(dict(j=['1.2', '1.2k', '1.2M', '-1.2B']))
>>> df
shape: (4, 1)
┌───────┐
│ j     │
│ ---   │
│ str   │
╞═══════╡
│ 1.2   │
│ 1.2k  │
│ 1.2M  │
│ -1.2B │
└───────┘
```

How would I go about parsing the above to get:

```
>>> df = polars.DataFrame(dict(j=[1.2, 1_200, 1_200_000, -1_200_000_000]))
>>> df
shape: (4, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ j         │
│ ---       │
│ f64       │
╞═══════════╡
│ 1.2       │
│ 1200.0    │
│ 1.2e6     │
│ -1.2000e9 │
└───────────┘
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.str.extract.html) and [`str.strip_chars()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.str.strip_chars.html) to split the parts and then get the resulting number by using [`Expr.replace()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.replace.html) + [`Expr.pow()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.pow):

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('j').str.strip_chars('KMB').cast(pl.Float32) *
    pl.lit(10).pow(
        pl.col('j').str.extract(r'(K|M|B)').replace(['K','M','B'],[3,6,9]).fill_null(0)
    )
)

┌─────────────┐
│ j           │
│ ---         │
│ f64         │
╞═════════════╡
│ 1.2         │
│ 1200.000048 │
│ 1.2000e6    │
│ -1.2000e9   │
└─────────────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution similar to that of @RomanPekar would be to replace `k`, `M`, and `B` with the corresponding SI multiplier directly.

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('j').str.strip_chars('kMB').cast(pl.Float32) *
    (
        pl.col('j')
        .str.extract(r'(k|M|B)')
        .replace({"k": 1e3, "M": 1e6, "B": 1e9}, default=1.0, return_dtype=pl.Float32)
    )
)
```